# Cannot find contract attachment for Cash when using NodeDriver

Tags: corda

I just started using Corda. I know that in unit testing, I'm supposed to add the line

```
setCordappPackages("net.corda.finance")
```

But when I debug using NodeDriver, I just receive the message.

```
net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for [net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash]
```

What's missing?

Comment: Please post your unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the packages the driver scans as follows:

```
driver(
    startNodesInProcess = true,
    extraCordappPackagesToScan = listOf("net.corda.examples.attachments"),
    isDebug = true) 
{
    ...
}
```